# Android NullPointerException error when assign two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, json, nullpointerexception

i have A Json response from my site and i parse that response. i can write to screen this parsing data without problem but i take a NullPoniterException error when i want to assign two dimension array.

i defined array and jsonarray and jsonobject like this ...

```
final String[][] sonuclarDizi = null;
    String kayitSayisi = jObj.getString("kayitSayisi");
 int kayitsay = Integer.parseInt(kayitSayisi.toString());
 JSONArray menuitemArray = jObj.getJSONArray("sonuclar");


for (int i = 0; i < kayitsay; i++) {
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun sube id si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sube_id"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun ders_id si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ders_id"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun kodu si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("kodu"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun adi si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("adi"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun ortalama_yazi si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ortalama_yazi"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun sube id si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("kredi"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun devamDurumu si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("devamDurumu"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun sube id si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ortalama"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun sonuc si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sonuc"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun sube id si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("basarili"));
                                System.out.println(i+". sonucun harf si "+menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("harf"));
                            }
```

this part is working. But below part return NullPointerException error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < kayitsay; i++) {
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sube_id"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ders_id"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("kodu"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("adi"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ortalama_yazi"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("kredi"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("devamDurumu"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ortalama"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sonuc"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("basarili"));
                                sonuclarDizi[i][1]=(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("harf"));
                            }
```

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

`sonuclarDizi` is a null array.  You declared it, but you need to instantiate it before you can add items to it.

```
String[][] sonuclarDizi;

sonuclarDizi = new String[kayitsay][];

for (int i = 0; i < kayitsay; i++) {
  sonuclarDizi[i] = new String[11];
  /* ... */
}
```